# How to add any url to Chrome history in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome

I am creating React project.

Sometimes I need to navigate to any URL.

e.g. localhost:3000/users/admin/12 or localhost:3000/users/manager/24

Of course, when I input these URLs to chrome at least one time, the Chrome will display or recommend these URLs.

But I want to let chrome recommend any URL from chrome history, although I never visited.

For this, I want to add any URL to chrome history.

I found a solution to read chrome history using https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-browser-history.

This is the package just reading history, not write.

I need to write chrome history.
How can I do it in React or any JavaScript?

Comment: I want to add history, Not read from history.

Comment: Chrome history is NOT something you can mess with.. Especially with javascript from a web application. The suggestions that come up when you start typing are either already visited URLs or google search suggestions. In the first place, why do you need to write to chrome history? Maybe there is another solution to your problem